# Is it possible to send a response from a service, but return something else?

Tags: 8

I have a block that returns a render array. I would also like to set a cookie value as well in this process. Is it possible to set a cookie and also return a render array?

Comment: Cookies aren't sent, they are set, and can then be retrieved anywhere in your code. They are independent from Drupal, so yes, you can. But it's likely not the Drupally way to achieve whatever it is your greater goal is.

Comment: Sorry, was coming at this from a Symfony response angle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still use setcookie/setrawcookie in Drupal, if you are sending a response, you can use Symfony to set one:

```
$cookie = new Cookie('name', 'value', $expire, '/', 'domain', TRUE, TRUE, TRUE);
$response->headers->setCookie($cookie);
```

vs

```
setrawcookie('name', 'value', $expire, '/', 'domain', TRUE, TRUE);
```

Note that the [internal Drupal function that writes a cookie](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_cookie_save/8.9.x) adds a prefix that you probably don't want.

Comment: Because of the symfony abstraction layers you shouldn't send cookies or responses containing cookies.